# How can I insert a new record in Access using a trigger?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2016

Bearings first...

Microsoft Access.
Version?  Unsure.  For that I see 
"Microsoft Office 365 Pro Plus" and
"Access 2007 - 2016 file format"

I'm a MS Access novice, but rather good at relational DBS (Postgres, MySQL, etc...) in which I've created triggers and their companion stored prodecures.

I'm trying to effectively create an after update trigger for a table.  I want the trigger to insert a record in a different table with values that I can either echo or customize based on values in the table that was just updated.

In the "table" tab, "after update", this is what I'm defining...

```
If [Old].[est_mandays]<>[est_mandays]  Then
    Create a Record In   ajax_hist
        Alias ah
    SetField
        Name ah.est_mandays
        Value = [Old].[est_mandays]
    SetField
        Name ah.id
        [Old].[id]
End If
```

As you can see, I'm just echoing those 2 values in the ajax_hist table.

It seems to swallow this OK as far as syntax.  At least I don't get any errors.  But when I change the value of est_mandays for a record in the table which has the trigger, no record is inserted in the ajax_hist table.  No messages of any kind, error, warning or otherwise.

I "saved" the table after the update in an attempt to force the change (just in case).  No difference.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

More importantly, is there a way to debug this (a log file or debug mode or something that tells me the trigger was actually fired ?)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Google debugging Access macros. I don't use macros, only VBA. I would execute an SQL INSERT action.

Comment: Start by checking the USysApplicationLog table. That contains the error log for data macros. Report back any errors in there

Comment: The USysApplicationLog table ?
How can I find that ?

Comment: Ah, I found out how to open USysApplicationLog and found the error in the Descriptin.  I should not have specified the values as [Old].[est_mandays] and [Old].[id].  Got rid of the [Old]'s and it works fine.  Thanks for the USysApplicationLog tip !  That did it.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the "[Old]." where setting values.
Thanks to Erik von Asmuth for the tip on USysApplicationLog which gave me the clue I needed.